# how can i draw an object in 2D at the center at openGl?

Tags: opengl, graphics

I need to draw a triangle in 2d at  the center of the screen and rotate it at the center only using a passive mouse actions any reference code?

```
void myDisplay(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); // clear the screen

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glVertex2i(100, 50); // draw three points
        glVertex2i(100, 130);
        glVertex2i(150, 130);
    glEnd();

    glFlush();
```

#### This is the image and the triangle:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsQTt.png]

Comment: Could you clarify a little bit? Is this a 2d only scene or a 3d scene with 2d content? And what do you mean by "rotate using passive mouse action"?

Comment: Query mouse position, calculate angle between x-axis and vector from center to mouse-position. Then rotate the triangle according to that angle

Comment: it is a 2d only i need to rotate it by the mouse at the center like the white triangle in the image

Comment: @BDL can you please support me with example code

Comment: finding the mouse-position depends on which environment you use to create the OpenGL window. Just check the documentation there. [Angle between two vectors can be found here](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/algebra/vectors/angleBetween/). Rotation in OpenGL is done via glRotatef, which is covered by nearly all OpenGL tutorials. In general we can help you to find the solution yourself, but we will not provide you with working source.

Comment: @BDL i do not need a working source just provide me with the idea to connect the mouse with the rotation

Answer (score 0):

Assume we have a triangle with one vertex lying in the center of the screen (NDC=[0,0]), that is symmetric along the x-axis. The problem of letting the triangle point to the mouse is than the problem of finding the angle between the vector going from the center of the screen to the mouseposition and the x-axis ([1,0]). A solution for doing this can look like the following:

```
Vec2 mousePosition = queryMousePositionAsDoneInYourAPI();
float angle = acos(dot(normalize(mousePosition - [width/2, height/2]), [1,0]));

glLoadIdentity();
glRotatef(angle, 0,0,1);

glBegin();
drawTriangle
glEnd();
```